# Missing Using directive for hierarchical_grouping in MSDN crystal reports tutorial

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, namespaces, visual-studio-2005, using

I was working through the MSDN tutorial for Crystal Reports, and I get to the Binding the Embedded Report to the CrystalReportViewer Control step:

When I try the build, it tells me that I am missing my `using` declaration for Hierarchical_Grouping class. This brings up two questions for me...

1. What is the namespace for this class definition?
2. Is there an easy way of determining the namespace of a given class?

In another answer I saw the 'ALT, SHIFT, F10' and the 'CTRL, [period]' suggestions for intellisense, but they don't work in my Visual Studio.

I'm sure I have done something ridiculously stupid....sorry in advance....

Here's the code for the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace CrystalTest3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Hierarchical_Grouping hierarchicalGroupingReport;

        public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
        {
            hierarchicalGroupingReport = new Hierarchical_Grouping();
            crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = hierarchicalGroupingReport;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfigureCrystalReports(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referring to [this tutorial.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227452%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The `Hierarchical_Grouping` seems to refer to the report file - which will contain the class named `Hierarchical_Grouping`. Have you added the report to your project?

The report should be somewhere in these [Sample Reports Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225622%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did find the sample report. But I ran into so much trouble just trying to get the tutorial working, I instead went with a solution modifying an existing word document. This worked out much better for the end users, cause they can modify the documents easily, add additional place holders, etc.    But I do appreciate the response!